# Merging of data through java application

Tags: java, database

I am developing a web based java application.  Application is territory based sales management system. Sales data are against territories. I have to implement a functionality of merging two territories into one territory. How can I implement it in application and reflect in database.
If two territories are merged into one territory then I want to show sum of sales of both the territories. I dont want to add both the rows and then show it because later on they can be merged into some other territory and it will be a huge mess up.

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Questions here tend to be fairly specific questions which already involve some code. Your question is very vague so it might be closed or voted down.

Comment: Didnt get the crux of the problem. So problem is that your code will have to be rewritten for new data or the old data will be irrecoverable?

Answer (score 0):

Here something you need Online analytical processing ? See [OLAP cube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP_cube)

Try [Openi](http://openi.org) or [Pentaho Analysis Services (Mondrian)](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/). It provides enough reporting for multidimensional data.

**Cube    :** Sales 

 **Dimentions :** Territory, Time & Product

 **Measures :** SalesQty & SalesValue